# Why is Tableau returning Null for this Calculated Field

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a calculated field trying to calculate a simple percentage between two fields that is returning NULL

I have a calculated field trying to calculate a simple percentage between two fields:

`Sum([Field1])` returns values for all rows
`Sum([Field2])` returns values for all rows
`Sum([Field1])/Sum([Field2])` returns NULL for all rows`

This makes no sense to me. And even more infuriatingly
`Sum([Field1])*(1/Sum([Field2]))` returns the percentage as expected

So I'm at a loss as to why the simple percentage value is returning a NULL

Comment: Strange. Show some sample data records. And what dimensions you are using in the viz